# Fast jvm start / jvm persistancy - starting jvm with data from heap dump

Tags: java, jvm

I am developing an in memory data structure, and would like to add persistency.

I am looking for a way to do this fast. I thought about dumpping a heap-dump once in a while.

Is there a way to load this java heap dump as is, into my memory? or is it impossible?

Otherwise, other suggestions for fast write and fast read of the entire information?
(Serialization might take a lot of time)

-----------------edited explination:--------
Since my memory might be full of small pieces of information, referencing each other - and so serialization may require me to in efficeintly scan all my memory. reloading is also possibly problematic.

On the other hand, I can define a gigantic array, and each object I create, I shall put it in the array. Links will be a long number, reperesnting the place in the array. Now, I can just dump this array as is - and also reload it as is.

There are even some jvms like JRockit that utilize the disk space, and so maybe it is possible maybe to dump as is very quickly and to re-load very quicky.
To prove my point, java dump contains all the information of the jvm, and it is produced quickly.
Sorry, but serialization of 4GB isn't even close to being in the seconds dump is.

Also, memory is memory and there are operating systems that allow you a ram memory dump quicky.
https://superuser.com/questions/164960/how-do-i-dump-physical-memory-in-linux

When you think about it... this is quite a good strategy for persistant data structures. There is quite a hype about in-memory data bases in the last decade. But why settel for that? What if I want a fibonacci heap - to be "almost persistant". That is, every 5 minutes I will dump the inforamtion (quickly) and in case of a electrical outage, I have a backup from 5 minutes ago.

-----------------end of edited explination:--------

Thank you.

Comment: Would you prove your statement why *Serialization might take a lot of time* ?

Comment: I added an edited explination

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, there is no way to do this on HotSpot.

Objects in the heap have 2 words of header, the second of which points into permgen for the class metadata (known as a klassOop). You would have to dump all of permgen as well, which includes all the pointers to compiled code - so basically the entire process.

There would be no sane way to recover the heap state correctly.

It may be better to explain precisely what you want to build & why already-existing products don't do what you need.

Comment: Great. I am looking for a quick way to write memory from heap to disk, and to load it quickly.

Comment: @user967710 - Presumably this is on a SSD drive? What are your requirements for how quickly you need to read / write?

Answer (score 0):

Use Serialization. Implement `java.io.Serializable`, add `serialVersionUID` to all of your classes, and you can persist them to any `OutputStream` (file, network, whatever). Just create a starting object from where all your object are reachable (even indirectly).

I don't think that Serialization would take long time, it's optimized code in the JVM.

Comment: Actually, Java Serialization is one of the [slowest methods](https://github.com/eishay/jvm-serializers/wiki) of writing out data.

Comment: @Steven Thanks for the info, I wasn't aware of that. There's something to learn every day :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) or [jvisualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) to load your dump to analyze it. I don't know whether the dump file can be loaded and restarted again.